# Display data from SQLiteDatabase in a listView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I can currently display my data from the databas in a normal TextView. But I now want to display the rows in the database in a listview, I've tried to do this with a cursor I can't seem to figure it out.

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ekonomi.db";

    public static final String TABLE_UTGIFTER = "utgifter";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TITEL = "_titel";
    public static final String COLUMN_KATEGORI = "_kategori";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRIS = "_pris";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATUM = "_datum";

    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_UTGIFTER + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_TITEL + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_KATEGORI + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_PRIS + " INTEGER, " +
                COLUMN_DATUM + " TEXT" +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addUtgifter(Utgift utgift){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITEL, utgift.get_titel());
        values.put(COLUMN_KATEGORI, utgift.get_kategori());
        values.put(COLUMN_PRIS, utgift.get_pris());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATUM, utgift.get_datum());
        db.insert(TABLE_UTGIFTER, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public String databaseToString() {
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_UTGIFTER + " WHERE 1";

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_titel")) != null) {
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_titel"));
                dbString += ", ";
//                dbString += "\n";
            }if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_kategori"))!=null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_kategori"));
                dbString += ", ";
            }
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_pris"))!=null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_pris"));
                dbString += ", ";
            }
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_datum"))!=null){
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_datum"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
}


public class VisaUtgiftFragment extends Fragment {
    private MainActivity ui;
    private TextView tvDatabase;
    private MyDBHandler dbHandler;
    private ListView lvUtgift;



    public VisaUtgiftFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void setActivity(MainActivity ui){
        this.ui = ui;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_visa_utgift, container, false);
        tvDatabase = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvDatabaseTest);
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity(), null, null, 1);
        tvDatabase.setText(dbHandler.databaseToString());
        lvUtgift = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvUtgift);
        lvUtgift.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, [the rows in the database]));
        lvUtgift.setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewClicked());

        return view;
    }

    private class ListViewClicked implements android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like the [sample code in this guide here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html).

The example uses a `CursorLoader` which may be used with a `ContentProvider` ideally, but you can use just the `SimpleCursorAdapter` passing in the cursor from your query without the `CursorLoader`. It will show the content of the cursor in a ListView all on its own.

Your code will look like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_visa_utgift, container, false);

    tvDatabase = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvDatabaseTest);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity(), null, null, 1);
    tvDatabase.setText(dbHandler.databaseToString());

    lvUtgift = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvUtgift);
    lvUtgift.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            dbHandler().getAllItemsInCursor(),
            new String[]{"_titel"},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
            0));
    lvUtgift.setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewClicked());

    return view;
}
```

And you will additionally have to add the below method in your `MyDBHandler` class:

```
public Cursor getAllItemsInCursor() {
    return getWritableDatabase()
            .rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_UTGIFTER, null);
}
```

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is the resource ID of a predefined layout that has just one `TextView` with resource ID `android.R.id.text1`.

You can replace `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` with a layout of your own that probably has more `TextView` to be able to show all the details in your table. Your own layout may look like:

utgifter_item.xml in `res/layout` directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_price"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_datum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And call to the constructor of `SimpleCursorAdapter` will be changed to:

```
lvUtgift.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.utgifter_item,
            dbHandler().getAllItemsInCursor(),
            new String[]{"_id", "_titel", "_kategori", "_pris", "_datum"},
            new int[]{R.id.item_id, R.id.item_title, R.id.item_category, R.id.item_price, R.id.item_datum},
            0));
```

Comment: what would R.id.text1 represent? And also thanks for trying to help me! and also how do i display all the rows in the database, not just _titel?

Comment: `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is the resource ID of a predefined layout that has just one `TextView` with resource ID `android.R.id.text1`.

You can replace `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` with a layout of your own that probably has more `TextView` to be able to show all the details in your table.

Comment: @Amar Added more details to the answer addressing your exact problem of displaying all the data from your database in a `ListView`.

Comment: How would I do this with an image, adding an imageView and a textview to the listView? I need 5 different pictures and depending on the category i get from the database It should be drawn in the listView. Can you help me sir?

Comment: You will need to write your own adapter for that...

You may create a class that extends `ArrayAdapter` and implement its methods like `getView` to do exactly what you need. Refer this guide here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: Isn't that a gridview? is it the same concept for listview?

Comment: Yes, just the presentation is different. Its the same to use at the basic level.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem? ArrayAdapter cosntructor has List as third argument so you have to get List that represents your db rows instead of one String that you get through databaseToString() method. Change your method to return List and pass it as ArrayAdapter constructor

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourListOfStrings);
```